# Remove Google login button from map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Has anyone an idea how i can remove the google login button from the map i created via JS? Haven't found anything in the docs so far.

[image]

```
var map;
var opt = {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng('some adress'),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmapdiv"), opt);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=false"></script>
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anandgh/7bmpfesu/

You can read more about this on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/signedin